# Permutations - restriction of having number be greater than and even (no repetition of numbers)

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Using $6$ numbers - $3,4,5,6,7,9$; a $6$-digit number is to be formed.
What is the working to find out how many of these $6$ digit numbers are even **and** greater than $500,000$?

**My attempt:**

When the first digit can be either $5,7,9$ and the last digit can be either $4,6$ - the possible amount of numbers is $3 \cdot 4 \cdot 3 \cdot 2 \cdot 1 \cdot 2$. (I'm getting this part correct according to the mark scheme). When the first digit can be either $5,6,7,9$ and the last digit can only be $4$, the possible ammount of numbers is $4 \cdot 4 \cdot 3 \cdot 2 \cdot 1 \cdot 1$ (I'm getting this part wrong according to the mark scheme). The answer I am getting is $240$. The current answer is $168$.

Comment: Can a digit be repeated? And what have you tried? Would you be able to solve it with none of the restrictions? With only one of the restrictions? Where are you stuck?

Comment: @Arthur no digit can be repeated. The first 2 subparts of the question were to find out how many 6 digit numbers are even, or are greater than 500,000- I got the answers as 240 and 480 respectively (which are correct as per the mark scheme). I have no idea how to tackle this restriction

Comment: Consider cases, depending on whether the leading digit, which must be at least $5$, is even or odd.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig When the first digit can be either 5,7,9 and the last digit can be either 4,6- the possible amount of numbers is 3*4*3*2*1*2. (I'm getting this part correct according to the mark scheme). When the first digit can be either 5,6,7,9 and the last digit can only be 4, the possible ammount of numbers is 4*4*3*2*1*1 (I'm getting this part wrong according to the mark scheme). The answer I am getting is 240, the current answer is 168.

Comment: @DeSith  You should place your attempt in the question rather than the comments.  You can do this by clicking the [edit] button at the bottom of your post.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observe that the leading digit must be at least $5$.  Consider cases, depending on whether the leading digit is even or odd:

1. If the leading digit is odd, the units digit may be selected from $4$ or $6$.  Choose the leading digit from among $5$, $7$, or $9$, choose the units digit, then arrange the remaining digits between them.
2. If the leading digit is $6$, the units digit must be $4$.  Arrange the remaining digits between them.

> In case 1, the number can be selected in $3 \cdot 2 \cdot 4!$ ways.  In case 2, it can be selected in $4!$ ways.  Hence, there are $$3 \cdot 2 \cdot 4! + 4! = (3 \cdot 2 + 1)4! = 7 \cdot 4! = 168$$ admissible arrangements.